# Freeing multidimensional arrays in C

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, multidimensional-array, free

Let's say we have:

```
void createMultiArray(){
    int i,j;
    char*** codes = malloc(5 * sizeof(char**));
    for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
        codes[i] = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char*));
        for ( j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) {
            codes[i][j] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
        }
   }
```

How should I free `codes`?

```
free(codes);
```

or

```
int i,j;
for(i = 0; i <=4; i++){
    for(j = 0; j <= i; j++){
        free(codes[i][j]);
    }
    free(codes[i]);
}
free(codes);
```

Comment: The second one doesn't result in a memory leak :) which is preferable.

Comment: It's "preferable", we can say "one is right, the other no" ;)

Comment: this is not a multidimensional array that you are using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think about it this way - you should have a `free` for every `malloc`.

```
// you're allocating memory for codes
// must be freed with free(codes);
char*** codes = malloc(5 * sizeof(char**));

for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {

    // allocating memory for every element in codes
    // must be freed with free(codes[i]);
    codes[i] = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char*));

    for ( j = 0; j <= i; j++ ) {

        // allocating memory for every element in every element in codes
        // must be freed with free(codes[i][j])
        codes[i][j] = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));

    }
}
```

So yes, your second option is the correct one.

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.  It's also a good idea to free in the opposite order as allocation.  Especially in this multi-dimensional problem you will clobber pointers and leak if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

The second one is what you want, `free` can't and won't work recursively. Each time when you do a `malloc` think of the place where you're going to call `free`.

As a side note, **don't free the memory if the next thing you'll do is exit the program** - it's pointless and could take quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 3):

The second is correct, while the first one leaks memory. As a rule of thumb, you want to call  `free()` for every `malloc()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Preferably you don't use nested malloc()-s, if you can calculate the size of the array beforehand. You should allocate and free in one step ( making your life easier and reducing the chance of bugs ).

Answer (score 1):

The memory layout for `createMultiArray()` would be as follows:

```
            codes[i]       codes[i][j]
***         **             *      
+-+         +-+            +-+-+
|0|-------->| |----------->| | | 
+-+         +-+            +-+-+
|1|-----+                   | | 
+-+     |   +-+             | | 
|2|     +-->| |             | +------------- char
+-+         +-+             +--------------- char
|3|         | + 
+-+         +-+ 
|4| 
+-+         ....            ....
```

Now, go back and free each memory you've created using free [yeah, for each `malloc()` there should be a `free()`]

OTOH, are you sure you want to do this?

```
for ( i = 0; i <= 4; i++ ) {
    codes[i] = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char*));
    ....
}

for i=0, malloc will create 1 memory cell
for i=1, malloc will create 2 memory cell
for i=2, malloc will create 3 memory cell
for i=3, malloc will create 4 memory cell
for i=4, malloc will create 5 memory cell
```

Is this intentional?

Comment: I did the `codes[i] = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char*));` because in next line i do `for ( j = 0; j <= i; j++ )`. Isn't that ok?

Comment: This is fine! ..I'm just curious whether that is intentional or not! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use such complicated allocation schemes to emulate multidimensional arrays. In your case in particular, where all bounds are compile time constants.

```
char (*codes)[n][m] = malloc(sizeof(char[x][n][m]));
```

fulfills the same purpose and only needs one

```
free(codes);
```

at the end. If the context where you use that array is even bound to one scope and your bounds are small you could even allocate it directly as `auto` variable and even initialize it at the same time

```
char codes[23][2][5] = { { { 'a', 'b'}  } };
```

no need to free at the end.

Comment: Hey, this answer will help me in future for sure!! But in this case my code was just an example, the size of my array is not a constant but it's determined at run-time. Thank you ;)

Comment: @Psyclops as long as you're using C99, all of this can happen at runtime.